# Pygame can't run over 60 FPS

Tags: python, timer, pygame, pygame-clock

I'm running a Pygame simulation with Python 3 on OSX. For some reason I cannot exceed 60 fps, but ideally I would be able to run it very high to run multiple trials in a short amount of time.

Im using `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` at the top of my main, and then:

```
while True:
    clock.tick(1000)
    print(clock.get_fps())
```

Any suggestions for how I could get my clock to run faster? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick

> Note that this function uses SDL_Delay function which is not accurate
>   on every platform, but does not use much CPU. Use tick_busy_loop if
>   you want an accurate timer, and don’t mind chewing CPU.

**`tick_busy_loop`** reference: http://pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick_busy_loop